# Compare filesystem space usage over time

Tags: linux, shell, unix, filesystems, visualization

Is there a good, graphical way to represent disk usage **changes** in a linux/unix filesystem over time?

Let me elaborate: there are several good ways to represent disk usage in a filesystem. I'm not interested in summary statistics such total space used (as given by du(1)), but more advanced interactive/visualization tools such as ncdu, gdmap, filelight or baobab, that can give me an idea of *where* the space is being used.

From a technical perspective, I think the best approach is squarified tree-maps (as available in gdmap), since it makes a better use of the visual space available. The circular approach used by filelight for instance cannot represent huge hierarchies efficiently, and it's dubious how to account for the increasing area of the outer rings in the representation from a human perspective. Looks nice, but that's about it.

Treemaps are perfect to have the current snapshot of disk usage in the filesystem, but I'd like to have something similar to see how disk usage has been *evolving* over time.

My current solution is very simple: I'm dumping the filesystem usage state using "ncdu -o" over time, and then I compare them side-by-side using two ncdu instances. It's very inefficient, but does the job. I'd like something more visual though.

All the relevant information can be dumped using:

```
find [dir] -printf "%P\t%s\n"
```

I did a crappy hack to load this state information in gdmap, so I can use two gdmap instances instead. Still not optimal though, as a treemap will fit the total allocated space into the same rectangle. As such, you cannot really tell if the same area is equivalent to more or less space. If two big directories grow proportionately, they will not change the visualization.

I need something better than that. Obviously, I cannot plot the cumulative directory sizes in a simple line plot, as I would have too many directories.

I'd like something similar to a treemap, where maybe the color of the square represents size increase/decrease using some colormap. However, since a treemap will show *individual* files as opposed to directories, it's not obvious on how to color-map a directory in which the allocated space has been growing/shrinking due to new/removed files.

What kind of visualization techniques could be used to see the evolution of allocated space over time, which take the **whole** underlying tree into account?

To elaborate even more, in a squarified treemap the whole allocated space is proportionally divided by file size, and each directory logically clusters the allocated space within it. As such, we don't "see" directories, we see the proportional space taken by it's content.

How we could extend and/or improve the visualization in order to see how the allocated space has been moved to a different area of the treemap?

Comment: I think your first problem is that you don't really know what you're looking for. Do you want to know in advance when the file system will be full? Do you want to know what the largest files are? Which folder changed size most drastically? Maybe ask yourself which problem you want to solve with this information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Unix & Linux StackExchange

Comment: Some minor clarifications: what I'm looking for is exactly what's on the title. I'd like to see how allocated space in a filesystem has been evolving over time. I'm **not** looking for specific tools or look into the evolution of specific directories/files. I'm more interested in visualization techniques and/or algorithms to correctly color-map a treemap (for example) to achieve that using a simple script, for instance.

Comment: I improved the question to be more specific.

Comment: why not use a scheduled cron job to append data (from du or whatever) to a csv file and open it in a spreadsheet with graphing capability like gnumeric, mtcelledit, siag, oleo, sc/xspread ?

Comment: Because I already have the data. The problem is how to visualize/summarize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can usee Cacti for this.
You need to install snmp deamon on you machine and install cacti (freeware) localy or on any other PC and monitor you linux machine.

http://blog.securactive.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/cacti_performance_vision1.png

You can monitor network interfaces, spaces of any partitions and lot of other parameters of your LINUX OS.

1. apt-get install cacti
2. vim /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

   add this at about 42 line:

   ```
   view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1
   ```

   close and restart snmpd deamon
3. go to cacti config and try to discover your linux machine.

Comment: Please note that cacti doesn't offer anything better than a simple summary of the space usage of a directory or a partition. I'd like a visualization that can show how the **overall** allocated space has been shifting over time, possibly at multiple time points.